# bootstrap video carousel fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering about someone could help me with my bootstrap carousel. my problem is that the opacity won't take effect with transitions or filter. i can see the css class and id´s work by google inspect. 
if someone can help me. I will be thankful.
My link to my website. http://alpha.mikemcfly.dk/JustAGeek.dk/

Under the tag work, you can see some buttons on left. There is the carousel with video and images.

```js
$('#carouselOne').carousel();
```

```css
#gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container {
 border: 1 pxsolid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
 margin-top: 0vh;
 margin-left: 0vw;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
 transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
}
#gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container.carousel {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
#gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container.carousel.carousel-inner {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
#gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container.carousel-fade.carousel-inner.item {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 transition-property: opacity;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .4s;
 -moz-transition: opacity .4s;
 -o-transition: opacity .4s;
 transition: opacity .4s;
}
#gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container.carousel-fade.carousel-inner.active {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .4s;
 -moz-transition: opacity .4s;
 -o-transition: opacity .4s;
 transition: opacity .4s;
 opacity: 1;
}
#gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container.carousel-fade.carousel-inner.active.left,
#gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container.carousel-fade.carousel-inner.active.right {
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 1;
}
#gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container.carousel-fade.carousel-inner.next.left,
#gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container.carousel-fade.carousel-inner.prev.right {
 opacity: 1;
}
#gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container.carousel-fade.carousel-control {
 z-index: 66;
}
@media all and(transform-3d),
(-webkit-transform-3d) {
 #gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container.carousel-fade.carousel-inner>.item.next,
 #gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container.carousel-fade.carousel-inner>.item.active.right {
  filter: opacity(0%);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
 #gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container.carousel-fade.carousel-inner>.item.prev,
 #gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container.carousel-fade.carousel-inner>.item.active.left {
  filter: opacity(0%);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
 #gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container.carousel-fade.carousel-inner>.item.next.left,
 #gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container.carousel-fade.carousel-inner>.item.prev.right,
 #gallery-buttons div.btn div div div.five.container.carousel-fade.carousel-inner>.item.active {
  filter: opacity(100%);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarouselOne" class="carousel carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarouselOne" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarouselOne" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarouselOne" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

            <div class="item active">
                <img src="content/images/1 project visual studio.mp4.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item ">
                <img src="content/images/1 project visual studio.mp4.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item ">
                <video src="content/videos/1 project visual studio.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls control muted/>
            </div>
            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarouselOne" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarouselOne" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @KrupeshKotecha The added spaces in the edit invalidate quite a few of those CSS selectors

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can see what you mean about the spaces. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Bootstrap carousel to be animated, you need to include the `.slide` class on your carousel div.

```js
$('#carouselOne').carousel();
```

```css
/* For testing purposes */
.carousel img {
  max-height: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
.carousel .carousel-indicators li {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarouselOne" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarouselOne" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarouselOne" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarouselOne" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51IwmuOPQyL._SL1052_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item ">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5Nj2BngIko0/maxresdefault.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item ">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51IwmuOPQyL._SL1052_.jpg">
      </div>
      
      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarouselOne" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarouselOne" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Great comment.

Comment: it's funny. why does the fade effect only work with src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js and not 3.3.1

Comment: It should work with 3.3.1. Just make sure that you're using the correct URL: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

Also, if you feel that this answer best solved your question, feel free to mark it as the solution to help future users.